# How to configure snmp for snmp trap forwarding

Tags: snmp

I have tried adding the following to `snmpd.conf`:

```
trapcommunity public
trapsink finalsnmptrapdestserver public
```

I thought this should allow traps to be recieved with the community string `public`
and send any traps to `finalsnmptrapdestserver` with community string `public`. But traps do not seem to make it to my final destination.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently snmptrapd needs to be used.

I created /etc/snmp/snmptrapd.conf with the following contents. Its not secure in any way but it did what I was wanting, though the problem I was originally trying to solve was not fixed. So back to the drawing board for me. But for anyone else wanting to proxy snmp traps a simple config.

```
authCommunity net public
forward default finalsnmptrapdestserver public
```

This will accept traps for forwarding with the community string public and forward all traps to finalsnmptrapdestserver with community string public.